Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'element')
Using vue-draggable with vue 3, getting the error in the title whenever I switch the order of my components, this is my code:
<draggable v-model="modules" item-key="id" handle=".module-handle" animation="200">
    <template #item="{ element }">
        <component
             v-if="element && registry[element.type]"
             :is="registry[element.type]"
             v-bind="element.props"
             :uid="uid"
             :edit="profileEdit"
        />
    </template>
</draggable>

and
const registry = {
   bio: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./components/Biography.vue')),
   media: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./components/Media.vue')),
   links: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./components/Links.vue')),
   music: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./components/Music.vue'))
}
const modules = ref([
   { id: 1, type: 'bio', props: {} },
   { id: 2, type: 'media', props: {} },
   { id: 3, type: 'links', props: {} },
   { id: 4, type: 'music', props: {} }
]);

Whenever you switch the order of the components by dragging with the handle they don't switch, bug out, and give errors such as "Undefined TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'element')" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'index')"

Please, provide a way to reproduce. Whether it's a bug in the library or unexpected behaviour, this needs to be debugged

What version of draggable library are you using?
